# How to solve Error Number: 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`smp`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ParentStudent` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`p_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>
> INSERT INTO `student` (`s_id`, `student_code`, `f_name`, `l_name`, `dob`, `gender`, `address`, `tel`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('', 'cbg', 'sdfsdf', 'sdfsd', '02/13/2019', 'male', 'fgfhnf', '', 'admin', 'pAQ7oL+r8QJNgy2siN5moyJUhrgSj5tq3Ai5U2ngMyvaQZDsS9ooPbfcCm8qKEWi1C6nbYdMCyscz6ngU+1Tiw==')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SMP/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

I get this error, and i think its something to do with my function in the controller

```
public function register_students()     {

    // $this->load->model('Register_model','multi_model',TRUE);
    $encrypted_password1 = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('p_pwd'));
    $parent_data = array(
        'p_id' => '',
        'parent_code' => $this->input->post('parent_code'),
        'f_name' => $this->input->post('p_first_name'),
        'l_name' => $this->input->post('p_last_name'),
        'dob' => $this->input->post('p_dob'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('p_address'),
        'tel' => $this->input->post('p_tel_no'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('p_username'),
        'password' => $encrypted_password1,
    );
        // var_dump($student_data);
        // var_dump($parent_data);

    $result = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('parent', $parent_data);
    $encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('pwd'));
    $student_data = array(
        's_id' => '',
        'student_code' => $this->input->post('student_code'),
        'f_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'l_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'tel' => $this->input->post('tel_no'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $encrypted_password,
    );
    $result = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('student', $student_data);
    // $result = $this->multi_model->student_register($student_data, $parent_data);
    if($result)         {
        redirect('student');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('student');
    }
}
```

model

```
 function insertTable($table, $data) {
     $this->db->insert($table, $data);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

CREATE TABLE `student` (
 `s_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `f_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `l_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `DOB` text NOT NULL,
 `gender` enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
 `tel` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`),
 KEY `s_id` (`s_id`),
 KEY `p_id` (`p_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ParentStudent` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`p_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `parent` (
 `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `f_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `l_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `DOB` text NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `tel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
 KEY `p_id` (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the PHP code I figured that you insert the parent first and the function you use to insert returns a parent id but you are not using it on the student insert. If you add it to the student array it will solve you problem:

```
public function register_students()     {
   {...}
   $p_id = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('parent', $parent_data); // Parent it returned

   $encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('pwd'));
   $student_data = array(
       's_id' => '',
       'p_id' => $p_id, // Adding parent id to student_data
       {...}
   );

   $result = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('student', $student_data);
   {...}
```

}

**Explanation about the SQL error**

You are getting this SQL exception error because on the `student` table you defined a **not null** foreign key `p_id` referencing `p_id` on the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (  
  s_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  student_code varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  f_name varchar(150) NOT NULL,  
  l_name varchar(250) NOT NULL,  
  DOB text NOT NULL,  gender enum('male','female') NOT NULL,  
  address varchar(450) NOT NULL,  
  tel int(50) NOT NULL,  
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  password varchar(150) NOT NULL,  
  p_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (s_id), 
  KEY s_id (s_id), 
  KEY p_id (p_id), 
  CONSTRAINT FK_ParentStudent FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES parent (p_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note that `p_id int(11) NOT NULL` makes it impossible for you to pass anything rather than a valid id reference to the `parent` table. That said, you cannot pass `''`or `null` or any other value than a valid id from the parent table. If you want this foreign key to have a default value edit your SQL to include a default value to `p_id` on the `student` table:

`p_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Thank you so much. it is finally working after adding '$p_id = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('parent', $parent_data);'.   You saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

If `p_id` is your primary key you are not supposed to pass it while insert. Remove this line `'p_id' => '',` from `$parent_data`

If you are unable to delete or update data. Please check foreign_key restriction on your database table, you may have ristricted it for so.

Comment: Thank you, I included my sql query. I think there are no restrictions